# Docker consuming more resources than specified in .wslconfig

Tags: docker, configuration, virtual-machine, wsl-2

I created a .wslconfig file following the first answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68706512/how-to-create-a-wslconfig-file) to limit wsl resource consumption on my Win10 os. It does not work and I have no clue why. I am using Docker Desktop. File:

```
# Limit the wsl or vmmem consumption of resources

[wsl2]
memory=3GB # Limits VM memory in WSL 2 to 3 GB
processors=3 # Makes the WSL 2 VM use 3 virtual processors
localhostForwarding=true # Boolean specifying if ports bound to wildcard or localhost in the WSL 2 VM should be connectable from the host via localhost:port.
```

- I am using windows build 19042.1526, which should be able to handle such file
- The file itself is actually a .wslconfig and not an accidental .txt
- I have restarted my PC and used `Restart-Service LxssManager` in  my admin powershell successfully
- I am actually using WSL 2
- I saved the file in `C:\Users\PC Paul` which is the main user

I am at my wits end, do you have any idea where the problem might be?

Thanks,
Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok it seems like the file has to start with [wsl2]. I deleted the comment at the top and now it seems to work.

Edit: Further help if it doesn't work may be found here: https://superuser.com/questions/1632543/wslconfig-not-applied-for-wsl2

Answer (score 1):

In my case I created the .wslconfig file by creating a new file like this:

[image]

After saving it the icons displayed was this:

[image]

I thought it should work because the name is correct.
But when I open the userprofile folder in command prompt and type in `dir`
it showed .wslconfig.txt

Solution:
Open command prompt, change directory and then rename file manually

```
cd %userprofile% 
rename .wslconfig.txt .wslconfig
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it turns out that the memory parameter is case sensitive.  I.e. you have to use `GB`, not `Gb`.  E.g. this works...

```
[wsl2]
memory=3GB
```

This *doesn't* work...

```
[wsl2]
memory=3Gb
```